# Multiple selector on field with multiple name []

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

**[Please ignore /close - I had made a mistake in my code but appreciate all the contributions]**

In my code I have a number of fields which share the same parent name. For example:

```
<input name="example[1_1]" type="checkbox">
<input name="example[1_2]" type="checkbox">
<input name="example[1_3]" type="checkbox">
```

I don't know which one of these is the checked value. Clearly I could use a class however what I would like to do is do a selector which says get all fields that start with the 1_.

I have tried the following:

```
var answer = $('input[name^="example['+q+']"]:checked').val();
var answer = $('input[name^="example['+q+'"]:checked').val();
```

Is this actually possible with Jquery?? If not I'll have to re-work my situation but if there is a way, I'd prefer to use that.

Comment: Your 2nd option seems to work fine: `$('input[name^="example['+q+'"]:checked')` https://jsfiddle.net/racsdng9/ - why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: Please keep in mind, if one of the answers works for you, please mark them as the answer to help other peoples in the community to find their solution easier if they facing the same issue. *If you don't know how to do it you can do this by using grey marks (tick) beside answers (you can only choose one), for more information please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)*. Otherwise please tell us why all of the provided answers do not work for you.

Comment: Did you come up with a conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [jQuery attribute selector documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors) the `^` selector will be

> `[att^=val]`
> Represents an element with the `att` attribute whose value begins with the prefix `"val"`. If `"val"` is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

So your selector does not have to contain the whole bracket in it. Then the final selector should be like this (Same as your second provided option):

```
input[name^="example[' + q + '"]:checked
```

So your final code should be something like this:

```js
var q = '1_'
var answer = $('input[name^="example[' + q + '"]:checked').val();
console.log(answer)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="example[1_1]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input name="example[1_2]" type="checkbox" value="2" checked/>
<input name="example[1_3]" type="checkbox" value="3" />
```

But your problem may not solve here, because, whenever you use a combination of `checked` and `.val()` it will only return the first matched element. So you need to get the whole matching elements then get their values separately.

You can get your final values like this:

```js
var q = '1_'
var answer = $('input[name^="example[' + q + '"]:checked');
var length = answer.length;

for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  console.log(answer[i].value)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="example[1_1]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input name="example[1_2]" type="checkbox" value="2" checked />
<input name="example[1_3]" type="checkbox" value="3" checked />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select all checkbox that is checked and where the name starts with `example[1_` you can use

```
var answer = $('input[name^="example[1_"]:checked')
```

**Demo**

```js
var answer = $('input[name^="example[1_"]:checked');

console.log(answer.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="example[1_1]" type="checkbox">
<input name="example[1_2]" type="checkbox" checked>
<input name="example[1_3]" type="checkbox">
```